# Class that holds objects of another class within an std::array unexpectedly goes into constructor of the subclass within the array

Tags: c++, class, constructor, containers

We are tasked to create a class based Todo-List. I have created a Class called Task and another one called List. List has an std::array as a member which contains objects of type Task. List has a member function that creates a task and one that prints the entire list.

The problem I'm facing is that the `std::array<Task,3>` declaration automatically calls the constructor of Task 3 times and writes the tasks into the array. This is less of a problem when using an array and saves me the `createTask()` function which I no longer need to call, but if i want to use a `Std::vector` to hold a variable amount of tasks i always get an error "vector subscript out of range". Additionally I only want to add a task when I want to, not until whatever container type is full. How do I go about tackling this problem?

```
class Task
{
private:
    std::array<std::string, 3> m_list;
    std::string m_completed{ "no" };
public:
    Task()
    {

        std::cout << "Enter Task Name: ";std::cin >> m_list[0]; //cant do white spaces yet
        m_list[1] = "23.04.2021"; //needs way of getting current date
        m_list[2] = m_completed;
        system("CLS");

    }

    void printTask()const
    {
        std::cout << "Task Name: " << m_list[0] << "         " << "created on: " << m_list[1] << "         " << "completed?: " << m_list[2] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << '\n';
    }

   
};  

class List{
private:
    std::array<Task,3> listOfTasks; //this automatically calls the constructor 3 times and writes the objects into the array 
    int m_vectorsize{ 0 };
public:
    List() {};
    
    void createTask()
    {
        Task t1;
        listOfTasks[m_vectorsize] = t1;
        ++m_vectorsize;

    }

    
    void printTasklist()
    {
        
        for (int count{ 0 }; count <3;count++)
        {
            
            listOfTasks[count].printTask();
            
        }

    }
    

    };
```

Comment: `std::vector` really seems to be a suitable data structure for your problem. Could you show us the code where you are trying to use it? And, please, format your code better. At least remove all unnecessary empty lines. Also, you should iterate in `printTaskList` only `m_vectorsize` times, not 3 times.

Comment: If you want to have a box of things, you first need to make the things, it's as simple as that.